# Поиск индекса подстроки в строке

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка, в которой несколько раз встречается подстрока, нужно получить порядковые номера вхождений и их координаты. В документации нашёл координаты а как порядковые получить не могу найти.

```
import re
for m in re.finditer(pattern, text):
    print('%2d-%2d: %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(0)))
```

Вывод:

```
1-4: pattern
18-21: pattern
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ну раз у вас уже есть некоторый итерируемый объект (`re.finditer(pattern, text)`), то оберните его в `enumerate` и получите на выходе для каждого элемента кортеж `(индекс, элемент)`

```
import re

pattern = "раз"
text = "раз два три раз три два раз раз"

for obj in enumerate(re.finditer(pattern, text)):
    print('%d | %2d-%2d: %s' % (obj[0], obj[1].start(), obj[1].end(), obj[1].group(0)))
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал про такую функцию